# Set up Visual Studio for using LINQ with Interbase

Tags: visual-studio-2010, linq, sharepoint-2010, firebird, interbase

I've recently come into possession of an *Interbase* SQL database. The database itself is from 2006. From my own research I've determined that the Interbase database can be connected to in one of two ways, either ODBC or ADO.NET 2.0.

I've managed to add an ODBC data connection in Visual Studio. My boss has decided that it's awful to perform queries this way and is convinced there's a way to use LINQ, maybe by using Firebird.

One of the constraints of the project is that we need to eventually connect the database to a SharePoint application. If anyone has any ideas for something that could work outside of SharePoint we're not opposed to creating a web service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Firebird, you can use [this](http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/net-provider/) Entity Framework provider. I don't know such providers for Interbase, but may be there is some too.

Comment: After much work, I didn't manage to get the database connected. I get an "Index out of range" error. I tried some more searching and have decided that the Interbase database won't work with Firebird. I'm just going to go with the ODBC connection. Thanks anyway.